# Why don't the Fn-hotkeys on my Asus N56 laptop work?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have a problem working with the Fn hotkeys on my brand new laptop Asus. I cannot change my volume, screen brightness, keyboard back light and other minor functions.
I have tested many possible solutions, but without any sucess.
Thank you!

I aprecciate some help!

Comment: +1 on this.
Can you please describe what you've already tried?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu release? and is it up-to-date?

Comment: I have the same problem on my Asus N56VZ. My Ubuntu release is 12.04 and is updated.

Comment: Diogo, can you post some details about your laptop?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try is to run `xev` from the terminal and try pressing the keys in question.

See what KeyPress events it reports. That might point to a solution you can find on your own or you could post them here.

Comment: I get no KeyPress events from the keys in question.

Comment: I was sure that the fn keys are handled on a lower level, and that these are actually driver related issues.

Comment: If they are all multimedia keys, they don't show up in xev. Sorry, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you're using 12.04 LTS, the hot key setting is more included with the default operating system. I has an ASUS eeePC 900 and when I went from Windows XP to Windows 7, I lost functionality of my function keys as you have. My recommendation, is to simply goto: *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts* (This is a tab located at the top.) and then create a custom short-cut as the computer has listed on the keyboard for the functions you desire. That would seem to be the easiest way, I don't know about keyboard backlight however, that sounds as if it would be managed with an included tool made specifically for the computer, not included with the operating system in question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution. You can see my answer to a similar question for the same hardware  [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/167418/76387) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, just reinstall the driver from the Asus website or CD. I've had this issue twice now. It's to do with your drivers.