#  FN keys not working on an Asus N56V

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, asus

The FN keys are not working

Using answer in 166261 question I installed the asus-wmi-dkms_0.2_all.deb.gz package

Now, using xev I see that the keys emit keycodes (for backlight keys xev says for fn-f3 and fn-f4 keycode 237)

But no keyboard backlight, also volume keys have no effect

Description of my framework:

===========================================================

Machine: Asus N56V laptop

===========================================================

Software

- Kubuntu 12.04 amd64
- kernel (3.5.0.5-generic) and drivers from xorg-edgers fresh X crack ppa

===========================================================

Hardware and problems

- after installation do not boot - SOLVED using boot-repair
- every couple of hours the system freezes - SOLVED using 3.5 kernel
- keybord FN keys - NOT WORKING
- Keyboard backlight - NOT WORKING
- Nvidia GEFORCE GT - NOT USED glxgears says 60 fps
- Ethernet Atheros card - SOLVED install alx driver
- external subwoofer - SOLVED adding options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4

==========================================================

Solutions

see the asnwers to the 162047 and 166261 questions

==========================================================

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/163984/73625) answer, it helped me with the FN keys and keyboard backlight.