# Why are the screen brightness keys on my ASUS N56VZ not working?

Tags: 12.10, brightness, asus, function-keys

All the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> work except  F5/F6 which control the screen brightness.

How can I get them to work?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried by updating the Kernel to the latest version. But I have found the best solution that can increase or decrease the brightness of the PC in Ubuntu using the function and brightness button. Just follow the steps:

Open terminal (Clt+Alt+T)  and run the command given below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now the new window opens and you will see the lines given below:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite_splice"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Now you have to change the lines above by the command lines given below:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Then save the window and Update the grub from the terminal using :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now you can Increase or decrease the brightness of your PC in Ubuntu 12.04 and the other versions also. This technique can be used in HP DV6, Acer Aspire, Dell Inspiron,  Toshiba and more others.

```
                    Hope this Helps!
                       RefreshIt
```

http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html

Comment: :< tried not working

Answer (score 1):

I have good news and bad news.
After a routine 12.10 update installed 3.7.0.4 kernal, F5 and F6 brightness keys work! The bad news is they only adjust about the top ten percent of the backlight brightness range.

Comment: tried not working :<
12.10

Comment: True. And every other time, you can't adjust all the way down even with the help of `xbacklight`. So if you want to use laptop in darkness, you need to keep rebooting until it works...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys, in case it's set up a "standard" keyboard?

Worth a quick try!

johncmd

Comment: they are bind as stop play forword backward fot N56VZ

Answer (score 0):

You can make all the function keys to work with Ubuntu 12.10. See my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/167418/76387) to a similar question.

Comment: :< tried not working